# Access to one (fixed) google account calendar from a java application

Tags: java, date, google-calendar-api

I am working on a small piece of software that requires the input of dates and times, preferably in a remote scenario.

I thought it would be an interesting idea to use Google Calendar as this method of input. It would allow simple access to all the events created by me.

I do not require it to access the events from the calendar of the user, but rather from one set and know account (that is hardcoded into the software).

I have only been able to find information on using OAuth2, to have users sign up with their own account.

Is it possible to hardcode access to one account into a java application? If so, could you give me a basic overview/point me towards some recourse that explain how to acconplish this?

If all of this is very complicated/unpractical, could you think of any other easy-to-setup method of entering dates/events remotly? I liked the idea of being able to set repeated events in google calendar, because I will most likely have a lot of repeated events. It would be great if the alternative supported something like it!

Thank you very much!

Comment: Looks like a [service account](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount) is what you need.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, Great :)

Answer (score 0):

You might take a look at what the Google Developers documentation calls a [service account](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount).

> The Google OAuth 2.0 system supports **server-to-server** interactions
>   such as those between a web application and a Google service. For this
>   scenario you need a **service account**, which is an account that **belongs
>   to your application instead of to an individual end user**.
>
> *Source: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount*